# Best way to log usage in VB.NET? (To a server)

Tags: vb.net, authentication, logging, ftp, upload

I have an application but for security reasons I need to keep track of who uses it. It will be used in my company and the users will be informed that their usage will be tracked. This is because it's dealing with some sensitive information so we need to know who has accessed it.

That said, I don't know how to approach this in a secure way. The simplest way would simply be to write computer name, Ip, etc etc to a text file and upload it to a FTP file server. However for this to be possible, I need to include the authentication details in the code which, if decompiled or otherwise seen would be very dangerous.

So I was wondering if there's any good/decent approaches to doing this in VB.NET?
Thanks.

Comment: Very broad topic and probably not appropriate for this forum. Really comes down to you but text file is probably the last thing I would use though.  You could use DB's, you could use windows event logs or you could use one of the many logging tools out there already

Comment: Putting the storage issue aside (the text file was just an example), I wanted to ask if anyone knew a good approach in vb.net to somehow send the usage data to a server for storage. Any way I can think of I would have to somehow put authentication details in the code - something I shouldn't do in a vb.net application. I also cannot have the users input this info themselves. It might be impossible, I just wanted to ask if anyone knows of an approach I could explore.

Answer (score 0):

In my project i used DBManager class where i did all my DB stuff, so to keep track of what users are doing, I wrote an function that fired up every time Data was edited, inserted, deleted etc, or even User has logged in, my function Inserted new data with query (what user has done), username, date, IP and so on...

It's not perfect, but it worked and I think this method is worth to recommend.

Comment: Yeah I am doing a similar thing but I was wondering how to store this information securely on a server without the user somehow being able to obtain the credentials or abuse it.